# Robolectric Resources$NotFoundException:drawable\abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID

Tags: android, robolectric

When I try to run :

```
Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class).getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction().add(mapFragment, "" + NavigationCtrl.FRAG_MAP).commit();
```

Robolectric throws an error :

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File build\intermediates\res\merged\dev\drawable\abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020013
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2091)
    at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethod(ReflectionHelpers.java:195)
    at org.robolectric.internal.Shadow.directlyOn(Shadow.java:57)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.loadDrawable(ShadowResources.java:225)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:695)

Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: XML file build\intermediates\res\merged\dev\drawable\abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): invalid drawable tag vector
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:897)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:837)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2087)
```

My other tests with Robolectric run correctly, it's only the "setupActivity" ones (there are several of them).

I know I could also start my fragment with `SupportFragmentTestUtil.startFragment(fragment)` but I need to pass the "tag" variable

Any idea ?

Comment: Which Android version are you testing?

Comment: Is it vector drawable?

Comment: I am using @Config(sdk = 18...) for my Runner. I use appCompat 24.1.1  and i have tried adding "vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true" to build.gradle

Comment: Material means that your sdk should be higher or at least `21`, not `18`. That's the reason of this eror

Comment: @piotrek1543 changing @Config(sdk = 18) to @Config(sdk = 21) did make my tests pass again. If you want to answer the question I can mark it as answered. Cheers.

Comment: @user2230304 I added as answer. Glad to hear I helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explanation

> Material means that your sdk should be higher or at least 21, not 18.
> That's the reason of this error.

#### Solution

Change `@Config(sdk = 18)` to `@Config(sdk = 21)` or with higher version.

It works.